# IndexError while printing in from csv

Tags: python, csv

While reading in from a CSV file of two columns and 36 Rows long, I reach line 25 and I have an error thrown.  I've checked in the file in two different editors and there isn't a newline or anything there.  I'm perplexed because the logic seems sound to me.

[Linked here](http://pastebin.com/SNPGqgBN) is the CSV file.

My traceback (including the last few printed lines) is as follows:

```
('Line', 23, 'http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/11/samsungs-growth-isnt-in-your-hand-its-in-your-laundry-room/')
('Line', 24, 'http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/11/now-theres-a-bug-bounty-program-for-the-whole-internet/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getArticleInformation.py", line 69, in <module>
    printCSV()
  File "getArticleInformation.py", line 63, in printCSV
    print ("Line", i, row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And the method doing the work in printing the method is as follows:

```
def printCSV():
    f = csv.reader(open("ArticleLocationCache.csv", "rb"))
    i = 1
    print (i)
    for row in f:
        print ("Line", i, row[1])
        i = i + 1
```

Any assistance in identifying my error would be amazing.  I've been trying to work it out for the last hour.

Comment: A test with your pasted data works for me.

Comment: Unrelated to the index error that I can't reproduce, there are some other things in your code that could be improved. First off, use a `with` statement to handle the file you're opening. Next, use `enumerate` to produce the `i` value as part of the loop, rather than handling it manually. Finally, make sure you're intending to print a tuple (if you are expecting `print` to work as a function in Python 2, try putting `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you are reading a row that doesn't have at least 2 elements on it. I'm not sure what you want to do with a row that doesn't, I suspect you just want to skip it. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
def printCSV():
f = csv.reader(open("ArticleLocationCache.csv", "rb"))
i = 1
print (i)
for row in f:
    if len(row)>=2:
        print ("Line", i, row[1])
        i = i + 1
```

Looking at your CSV file, it seems like you might not be parsing it correctly. As an alternative to figure out what's going on, try just printing the whole row out, and then figure out why it's not working as you want, as follows:

```
def printCSV():
f = csv.reader(open("ArticleLocationCache.csv", "rb"))
i = 1
print (i)
for row in f:
    print (row)
    print ("Line", i, row[1])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the earlier process of separating this information did a good job of separating the values of headers from hrefs into columns and rows.  There isn't a comma missing in the file.

Comment: I'll get back to you in a moment.  Gonna test with both of those.  Would you like to see my method for parsing the info and saving to csv?

Comment: With the former of the two, I receive the correct inputs all the way up through the 24th entry.

With the latter of the two of those, I receive:
`('Row', ['P'])`
Being the last thing printed before the same stacktrace

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think that your file just isn't correct on your local HD. Are you 100% sure it's complete?

Comment: I changed the written and read delimiters and the problem disappeared!
Thank you very much!