# Parsing CSV to chart stock ticker data

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I created a program that takes stock tickers, crawls the web to find a CSV of each ticker's historical prices, and plots them using matplotlib.  Almost everything is working fine, but I've run into a problem parsing the CSV to separate out each price.

The error I get is:

> prices = [float(row[4]) for row in csv_rows]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I get what the problem is here, I'm just not really sure how I should fix it.

(The issue is in the `parseCSV()` method)

```
# Loop to chart multiple stocks
def chartStocks(*tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        chartStock(ticker)
        
# Single chart stock method
def chartStock(ticker):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=" + str(ticker) + "+Historical+Prices"
    sourceCode = requests.get(url)
    plainText = sourceCode.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
    csv = findCSV(soup)
    parseCSV(csv)

# Find the CSV URL        
def findCSV(soupPage):
    CSV_URL_PREFIX = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='
    links = soupPage.findAll('a')
    for link in links:
        href = link.get('href', '')
        if href.startswith(CSV_URL_PREFIX):
            return href
    
# Parse CSV for daily prices
def parseCSV(csv_text):
    csv_rows = csv.reader(csv_text.split('\n'))

    prices = [float(row[4]) for row in csv_rows]
    days = list(range(len(prices)))
    point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

    for price in prices:
        i = 0
        p = point(days[i], prices[i])
        points = []
        points.append(p)
    print(points)

    plotStock(points)

# Plot the data
def plotStock(points):
    plt.plot(points)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Once you use @mhawke's answer to actually download the csv data and @Alexander's to handle rows with less than 5 items on them, then you also need to move the `points = []` out of the `for` loop near the end of `parseCSV()`.

Comment: The issue you *asked about* (dealing with an IndexError while processing CSV data) seems to be a duplicate of [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883776/indexerror-while-printing-in-from-csv) (or maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621595/indexerror-index-out-of-range-7) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786157/if-list-index-exists-do-x)). Of course, as several others have already pointed out, what you *thought* was the problem was actually the least of the issues in your code.

Comment: I believe this post is [under discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317124/how-to-deal-with-peer-pressure-to-change-the-answer-i-accepted?cb=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if your row has at least five elements (i.e. index location 4).

```
prices = [float(row[4]) for row in csv_rows if len(row) > 4]
```

Comment: .and this is a common problem with csv files that have a few extra empty lines in them. You'd think the csv parser would skip those lines, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is not the problem. The URL of the CSV resource is being passed to `parseCSV()`. The actual CSV data is never retrieved.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that `parseCSV()` expects a string containing CSV data, but it is actually being passed the *URL* of the CSV data, not the downloaded CSV data.

This is because `findCSV(soup)` returns the value of `href` for the CSV link found on the page, and then that value is passed to `parseCSV()`. The CSV reader finds a single undelimited row of data, so there is only one column, not the >4 that is expected.

At no point is the CSV data actually being downloaded.

You could write the first few lines of `parseCSV()` like this:

```
def parseCSV(csv_url):
    r = requests.get(csv_url) 
    csv_rows = csv.reader(r.iter_lines())
```

Comment: ..and after the OP does all that they'll see that the rows of data look like what is shown in the table [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL+Historical+Prices) — so the rest of their code for parsing and plotting the data also won't work.

Comment: @martineau: actually, after adding the row length check suggested in another answer,  I don't think that the OP will see anything at all - just a plot of an empty list.

Comment: I decided to forget about the CSV module and just parse it myself.  Works fine now :)

Comment: @123: so you are now downloading the CSV data?

Comment: @123: Oh, I see... is the data complete? There are pagination links at the bottom and clicking "next" gives the next page of results.

Comment: @martineau: indeed. Sometimes, it seems, that we just can not help :)